# Urn problem with balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say you have $2n$ black balls and an additional blue and a red ball.

If there exist two urns and you randomly throw $n+1$ balls in each, then what is the probability that you do not have both the blue and the red balls in the same urn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carry out the splitting and *then* color the balls.

Specifically, split $2n+2$ black balls between the urns and then randomly and independently color one ball blue and the other red.  The chance they are both in the *same* urn is the number of ways to choose two balls from one urn, plus the number of ways to choose them from the other urn, all divided by the number of ways *in toto* to choose two balls.  Subtracting this from $1$ gives the chance they are in different urns:

$$1 - \left(\binom{n+1}{2} + \binom{n+1}{2}\right) / \binom{2n+2}{ 2} = \frac{n+1}{2n+1} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2(2n+1)}.$$

This formula, because it is simpler than others that might be derived from the original description, lends itself to easy simplification and clearly shows just how close to $1/2$ the chance is.

Comment: Good job, I need to start thinking like this.

Comment: It might be even simpler just to count the ways of choosing one ball in one urn and the other in the other: $(n+1)^2$.  Divided by $\binom{2n+2}{2}$, this gives the answer directly.

Comment: Also, even easier yet: without loss of generality the red ball is in the first urn. The blue ball is equally likely to be any of the remaining $2n+1$ balls, so the probability that it’s in the second urn is $\frac{n+1}{2n+1}=\frac12+\frac1{2(2n+1)}$.

Comment: @Brian Thank you for that observation. It's very much in the spirit of this answer, which is an attempt to find as simple a solution as possible.

Comment: @whuber: It is indeed — and that was my motivation as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{2n+1}{n+1}$ ways to fill the first urn. But we only want those in which urn $1$ has both colored balls or none of them.

There are $\binom{2n-2}{n-1}$ which have both red and blue.

There are $\binom{2n-2}{n+1}$ which have neither.

Thus the answer is $$\frac{\binom{2n-2}{n-1}+\binom{2n-2}{n+1}}{\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}$$

Comment: aymptotically what is this?

Comment: does not make sense. asymptotically $2$.

Comment: why do you say it is asymptotically $2$?

Comment: $$\frac{\binom{2n-2}{n-1}+\binom{2n-2}{n+1}}{\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}$$
$$\approx \frac{\frac{2^{2n-2}}{\sqrt{(2n-2)\pi}}(1+\frac{(n-2)(n-1)}{n(n+1)})}{\frac{2^{2n+2}}{\sqrt{(2n+2)\pi}}}\approx\frac{1}{2}$$ Ok works out right.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a hypergeometric distribution. We choose for Urn 1, which fixes Urn 2. There are $2n$ black balls, and we choose $n$. Then we choose $1$ of the $2$ remaining balls, and divide out by the number of ways to choose $n+1$ balls:

$$\frac{ \binom{2n}{n} \binom{2}{1} } { \binom{2n+2}{n+1} }$$

Comment: Is this prob that both are in same urn or different urns?

Comment: Different urns. We have the $2n$ black balls and pick $n$. Then we have the red and blue balls, which are the remaining $2$. We choose one of the red + blue balls.

Comment: asymptotically close to half right?

Comment: Yes. If you break apart the combinations, what are the odds of both being in the same urn? You have $\frac{1}{2}$ that a given ball will be in urn $1$. So by rule of product, that is $\frac{1}{4}$ they will be in urn $1$. By rule of sum, we add the same probability for urn $2$. So that's $\frac{1}{2}$ they will be in the same urn.